# Can I Just Replace enable_if With decltype

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, decltype, enable-if

After [understanding `decltype` with 2 arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30309643/2642059) I am wondering, could I just use that instead of `enable_if`? For example:

```
template <typename T>
decltype(T(), declval<bool>()) isConstructable() { return true; }
```

Succeeds with `isConstructable<int>` and fails with `isConstructable<istream>` on Visual Studio 2015: http://rextester.com/YQI94257 But on [gcc I have to do](http://ideone.com/6ELUKo):

```
template <typename T>
enable_if_t<decltype(T(), true_type())::value, bool> isConstructable() { return true; }
```

Should the `decltype` version work, or am I just exploiting a non-standard Microsoftianisim?

Comment: if you use traits for `std::enable_if` you can have *true* and *false* version. it is not (always) possible with `decltype`.

Comment: @Jarod42 I'm actually just looking for a compile error in the event that the `decltype`/`enable_if` fails, so I wasn't intending to use this with a false specialization, though I can see how that is a use case not available to the `decltype` version.

Comment: @JonathanMee: If you just want a compile error, just write your template code as normal. If it results in code that can't work, you get a compile error.

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm actually interested in using this just as the actual [`is_constructable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constructible) is used in meta-programming. I'm just using construction as an MCVE, I actually have a function that I'm testing availability for and I *will* be using this function to force SFINAE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by [RustyX's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41700158/2642059) if you do:

```
is_rvalue_reference_v<decltype(isConstructable<int>())>
```

[On gcc you'll get `true`](http://ideone.com/jQnTp8) and [on Visual Studio you'll get `false`](http://rextester.com/NXBZL19003). So the reason this fails on gcc is that it's always undefined behavior to return an r-value reference to an object which is about to be destroyed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29332571/2642059

## Should `declval` return an r-value reference?

[`declval`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval)'s return type is actually:

> `T&&` unless `T` is (possibly cv-qualified) `void`, in which case the return type is `T`

Thus this is a "Microsoftianisim". Platform independent code could be accomplished by removing the `declval`:

```
template <typename T>
decltype(T(), bool()) isConstructable() { return true; }
```

[<kbd>gcc Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/1utUgX) [<kbd>Visual Studio Example</kbd>](http://rextester.com/OZLBE80889)

[Jarod42 has pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41699057/can-i-just-replace-enable-if-with-decltype?noredirect=1#comment70603346_41700158) that `T` may have overloaded the `,` operator in which case a buffering `void()` will be needed:

```
template <typename T>
decltype(T(), void(), bool()) isConstructable() { return true; }
```

Answer (score 1):

The type of `std::declval<bool>()` is `bool&&`, not `bool`. That's where the warning comes from - `true` needs to be returned by reference.

Something like this should compile without a warning:

```
bool ok() { return true; }

template <typename T>
decltype(T(), ok()) is_constructable() { return true; }

int main() {
    cout << is_constructable<int>() << endl;
}
```

Comment: Interesting, it seems that you are correct on gcc: http://ideone.com/jQnTp8 but incorrect on Visual Studio: http://rextester.com/NXBZL19003 So it seems that the `declval` implementation is the problem here.

Comment: `decltype(T(), void(), true)` should be enough. (`void()` added to avoid evil overload of `operator ,`)

Comment: @Jarod42 Good point, how would this play out in an `enable_if`? would I need to buffer with a `void` there too? How would I even handle that since `enable_if` accepts exactly 2 arguments.

Comment: @JonathanMee: it would be `std::enable_if_t<decltype(T(), void(), true_type())::value, bool>` (or in your case, with traits `std::enable_if_t<std::is_default_constructible<T>::value, bool>`)